# simple jolt transform to insert values object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to understand simple jolt transformations , I have a simple 1 level json , I would like to change the sequence of columns and convert into Rows array with Values object repeating with comma separated values, adding current date at the end of Values object.
And also add default tags

**Sample JSON**

```json
{
  "name": "john",
  "Address2": "123 Street 1",
  "Address1": "Apt 101",
  "custId": "ZY-1234",
  "zip": "67834"
}
```

**Expected JSON**

```json
{
  "Rows": [{
        "values": [
            "ZY-1234",
            "john",
            "123 Street 1",
            "Apt 101",
            "67834",
            "2022-09-01 10:10:09"
        ]
    }],
  "operationType": "Insert",
  "Source": "Dev"
}
```

**Jolt Spec I have**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "ChangedBy": "NIFI",
      "ChangedOn": "${now()}"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "Rows[#1].Values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      },
      "operationType": "Insert",
      "Source": "Dev"
    }
  }
]
```

**The Result JSON**

```json
{
  "Rows" : [ {
    "Values" : [ 
        "john", 
        "123 Street 1", 
        "Apt 101", 
        "ZY-1234", 
        "67834", 
        "NIFI", 
        "${now()}" ]
  } ],
  "operationType" : "Insert",
  "Source" : "Dev"
}
```

**Issues :**

1. How to change the column sequence in Values array
2. How to get current datetime

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee the order of columns, you'll need to specify where in the target array (i.e. indices) to put them. If your input is a single JSON object as you have above, you can use 0 for the Rows index and pick each of the fields individually to put them in their place in the values array. Try the following:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "custId": "Rows[0].Values[0]",
      "name": "Rows[0].Values[1]",
      "Address2": "Rows[0].Values[2]",
      "Address1": "Rows[0].Values[3]",
      "zip": "Rows[0].Values[4]",
      "#\\${now()}": "Rows[0].Values[5]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "operationType": "Insert",
      "Source": "Dev",
      "ChangedBy": "NIFI",
      "ChangedOn": "${now()}"
    }
  }
]
```

My output from JoltTransformJSON is as follows:

```json
{
  "Rows": [
    {
      "Values": [
        "ZY-1234",
        "john",
        "123 Street 1",
        "Apt 101",
        "67834",
        "Tue Sep 06 18:51:35 EDT 2022"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Source": "Dev",
  "ChangedOn": "Tue Sep 06 18:51:35 EDT 2022",
  "ChangedBy": "NIFI",
  "operationType": "Insert"
}
```

You can use additional NiFi Expression Language functions such as [toDate](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#todate) and [format](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format) or [toInstant](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#toinstant) and [formatInstant](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#formatInstant) to get the `${now()}` expression to give you the timestamp string you want.

Comment: The sequence of columns worked thanks , but the default date is not working in https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception OR in Nifi JoltTransformJSON processor 
is it some latest version of nifi

Comment: Yes, it works on Apache NiFi (the version of mine is JoltTransformJSON 1.13.1) while that dynamic content doesn't work on that playground @user10086251